# trigger ajax while adding new record in Mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working on live chat extension, I have successfully fetch the chat records when customer click sent button.

[image]

I am looking for when admin reply that message (new record added in database), while I need show that message automatically to customer.

I am using ajax for getting records.

```
   $(".csend").click(function () {
            var a=$(".typearea").val();
            if(a!="")
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://magentodev.gworks.mobi/magento2/livechat/ajax",
                    data: {
                        message: a
                    },
                    success: function (Response) {
                        $(".messagelist span").remove();
                        $(".messagelist").append(Response);
                    } // you had an extra );
                });
            }
        });
```

I hope someone handled the situation already. Please suggest what are the best way to achieve this?

I am not expecting a-z, just key points or hints or steps to achieve is enough.

**note:** without time looping is much appreciated.

Comment: Try this library http://socketo.me/

Comment: `note: without time looping is much appreciated.` How should the device know when new Content is sent ? without a Service ( which is Looping with time ) thats not easy to do. i would go with  `setintervall` and call every second or 5 secs

Comment: it means set time interval in ajax for continuously running script to detect changes.

Comment: I recommend using `WebSocket` connections for this. Open a ws connection on the client side and let the server send a ws response when the admin answers. That way you don't have to constantly try and pull the answer from the server. You can still use AJAX to send the message from the client.

Comment: You can install a node.js server with a websocket module and subscribe to messages from there.

Comment: I am working on Ratchet, it is very new to me. I have followed official doc and make one group chat but I bit lack about how to convert admin to client conversation(private room). client initiate chat and admin only responsible for reply. if you have any github code or article, please share with me, it is very useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion : Ajax is not solution for real time chat.you need to integrate socket programming. Please refer http://socket.io/ ,if you don't want to integrate it then please refer https://www.pubnub.com/solutions/chat/.

pubnub create publish -> subscriber socket

```
//PUBLISH
pubnub.publish({
        channel :  "PUBLIC_CHAT",
        message : "Hello!" });

//SUBSCRIBE
pubnub.subscribe({
        channel :  "PUBLIC_CHAT",
        message : callback });
```

Note : If you want solution from ajax then you have only one way "time interval" and check db for customer or admin last message like ->

```
var minutes = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  //get customer or admin last message from db
}, 1000 * 60 * minutes);
```

Comment: @BilalUsean,Ok fine any time.please let me know which method you will use pubnub or socket.io.

Comment: pubnub is only free upto 100 device connected. am I right?